# Spinner, setOnItemSelectedListener is not working for Spinner when items are selected

Tags: android

setOnItemSelecctedListener is not working for the spinner.   Following is the code in mainactivity.java. I have populated spinner in xml file using entries option.  When an item is selected, toast message is not displayed showing the item selected.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
  String[] presidents;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


if (savedInstanceState == null) {
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
.commit();
    } 

    presidents = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.presidents);

    Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    if(s1 != null){

        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                    View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
            {
                int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), presidents[index], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){

            }
        });
    }


}
```

}

```
activity_main.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">



<!-- Spinner Element -->
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:entries="@array/presidents"     
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"

/>
</LinearLayout>

Strings.xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">My First App</string>

 <string-array name = "presidents">
    <item>eisenhower</item>
    <item>kennedy</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: Is spinner expanding On click event ??

Comment: No, spinner is not expanding on click event.

Comment: Have you checked `presidents` size? what is it?Show your activity_main.xml file too.

Comment: presidents has three items, which are populated in main_activity.java file.  I have shown activity_main.xml file also.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your Spinner `s1` is null.

Your xml code:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
/>
```

In Activity, you use id `spinner1`

```
Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

So here s1 will be null.

And you check this:

```
if(s1 != null){
    s1.setAdapter(adapter);
    ...
}
```

Just change your id to `spinner` here:

```
Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

So `s1` won't be `null`, and it will be populated with data using adapter.

Hope it helps.

NOTE:

If you have spinner1 in a fragment, you would need to do something like:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    Spinner s1 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    return container;
}
```

Comment: In activity , i have changed the id to spinner.  Spinner is not showing items.

Comment: Id used in xml file and id used in activity are same.  Still the spinner is not showing items.

Comment: I have changed the code.  I have populated spinner with items in xml file using entries option.  Now the setOnItemSelectedListener is not working.  It is not displaying the toast message when an item is selected in spinner.

Comment: Answer 1 is no longer relevant.  It can be removed.